# Output of numrows that depends on current url

Tags: php, if-statement

Does anyone know how the following statement should be looks like? I've tryed multiple structures like while loops, and switch statements, but I cant figure it out. I know the following code is completly wrong, just want to show what I want

```
if($numrows > 0)
  {
    if($this->currentURL() == 'http://localhost/webshop/public/index.php?page=login.php')
      {
        $this->redirect();
      }
  }
else
  {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password!";
  }
if($numrows > 0)
  {
    if($this->currentURL() == 'http://localhost/webshop/public/index.php?page=register.php')
      {
        echo "Already in use!";
      }
  }
else
  {
    $this->insertRows();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want the logic to be like this,

```
 if($numrows > 0)
  {
      if($this->currentURL() == 'http://localhost/webshop/public/index.php?page=login.php')           
          $this->redirect();   
      else if($this->currentURL() == 'http://localhost/webshop/public/index.php?page=register.php')  
              echo "Already in use!";                 
          else      
              echo "Wrong Username or Password!";    
  }
  else         
      $this->insertRows();
```

Comment: Thanks, the else on the end looks weird, as in when it belongs to the first if